# I am suddenly getting an nvm install error message when launching terminal in Mac OS

Tags: node.js, zsh, nvm

When I launch terminal I am getting the following message that was not there before:

```
N/A: version "N/A" is not yet installed.

You need to run "nvm install N/A" to install it before using it.
```

I am using `zsh` as my shell and I have `nvm` configured properly from the install instructions and loading it in my `zshrc` file.

Answer (score 5):

The message is erroneously telling you to install a version of Node that doesn't exist, because you probably recently updated node and forgot to let nvm know to use it as the new default. To remove the message do the following:

1. `nvm ls` and take note of the N/A version that is default and the versions available
2. `nvm alias default v(whatever version you have updated to)` e.g. `nvm alias default v10.15` in my case.

The next time you load the shell the message should be gone.