# I keep getting 'You need to run "nvm install N/A" to install it before using it.' even tho I have already installed lts/*

Tags: nvm

```
nvm ls:

->       system
default -> system
unstable -> system
node -> stable (-> v12.16.3) (default)
stable -> 12.16 (-> v12.16.3) (default)
iojs -> N/A (default)
lts/* -> lts/erbium (-> v12.16.3)
lts/argon -> v4.9.1 (-> N/A)
lts/boron -> v6.17.1 (-> N/A)
lts/carbon -> v8.17.0 (-> N/A)
lts/dubnium -> v10.20.1
lts/erbium -> v12.16.3
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I am suddenly getting an nvm install error message when launching terminal in Mac OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58436696/i-am-suddenly-getting-an-nvm-install-error-message-when-launching-terminal-in-ma)

Answer (score 28):

use `nvm alias default v12.16.3` to set default version explicitly

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this updating the node to LTS version:

```
nvm install --lts
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, running `nvm alias default system` solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

**DISCLAIMER**: We were getting this error specifically trying to run
a React Native build for iOS in Microsoft AppCenter. The OP question did
not specify the environment so depending on your setup your mileage may
vary.

In our specific circumstance, the issue was resolved by bumping the
XCode version from 10.1 to 11.3.